# Hibernate Interceptors or Events for Audit Trail?

Tags: hibernate, spring, interceptor, audit-trail, hibernate-envers

I record a history of all changes to some entities and am about to implement a mechanism similar to [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) to take care of this automatically.  My question is whether to use Hibernate [interceptors or their event system](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html)?

It seems like interceptors is a little simpler and does all I need.  And Hibernate's own documentation suggests using interceptors for "tracking audit information."  But their audit information isn't in a companion table for each entity and Envers uses the event system I imagine for a reason.

I'm using Spring 3.0 and Hibernate 3.5 (latest stables).

***UPDATE***: database triggers are not desirable for this situation.  I'm eager to hear thoughts on hibernate interceptors vs events for audit trails/change histories.

Comment: Database triggers would be my preferred approach to this. Simpler than using Hibernate's interceptors.

Comment: DB triggers are not so easy with my app.  I need to record extra information in each audit entry, including the change that was reverted to, the change each change was based on, etc. and a cascading mechanism that handles this for collections.

Comment: @skaffman: triggers move logic into the database layer. Using an ORM, between others, helps us keep the logic where it belongs, in the application layer.

Comment: @cherouvim: Well, that's one opinion. I'd argue that audit tables are about data integrity, not business logic, and that *does* belong in the database.

Comment: I'd go with overwriting EmptyInterceptor. It is straight forward and easy to use. IMO the best thing about this is the AfterTransactionComplete-Method. Use other methods to collect changes and in AfterTxComplete check the Tx-State and on success persist your Audit-Logs before Interceptor-Reset.

Answer (score 2):

I think the essential difference between the two is that you can only define one Interceptor in your SessionFactory, but you can register many listeners for a particular event.

I'm going to use Interceptors since I only want something very simple: a timestamp when my entity is created (the `@Version` annotation takes care of updating the lastModified property).

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.x.domain" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="onSaveInterceptor" />
</bean>
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html#objectstate-interceptors